# jquery plugin: creation

Tags: jquery, json, plugins

The output am expecting is an unordered list which am creating with jquery...which takes in put from a json file (which works fine when i dont create it as a plugin). Am very new with the concept of building a plugin. i've tried to create one which doesnt output my unordered list

json file structure

```
{
    "Categories": [
    {
        "cat_id":"1",
        "name":"Main Menu1",
         "sub_categories":[
         {
             "cat_id":"10",
             "name":" Sub Menu11",
             "sub_level_one_link":"http:\/\/one.com"
         },
```

my js file

```
//create plugin 
jQuery.fn.emrMenu= function (options) {
    myoptions = jQuery.extend ({ url: "error" }, options);

    if (myoptions.url=="error") { alert("Error:No data recieved"); return false; }
    $(this).html (myoptions.url);

    return this.each (function () { 

        //alert(myoptions.url+this.id);

        $.getJSON(myoptions.url,  function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.Categories, function(i, category)
            { 
                alert("test1");
                //get all sub menu items in list indexes      
                var submenudata='';
                $.each(category.sub_categories, function(i, sub_categories)
                { 
                    submenudata += "<li><a href='"+sub_categories.sub_level_one_link+"' <span>"+sub_categories.name+"</span></a></li>";

                });
                var menudata ="<li id='"+category.cat_id+"' class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>"+category.name+"</span></a><ul>"+submenudata+"</ul></li>";                      
                //stringify unordered list and bind to div              
                var menu="<ul>"+menudata+"</ul>";

                //   $(menu).appendTo("#"this.id);
             });
        });           

        //alert (this.id);

    }); 
}
```

and am calling the plugin:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu_n').emrMenu ({ url: "menu_data.json"});

});
</script>
```

I'am pretty confused at this point any help is greatly appreciated cheers!

Comment: Do you get errors in the console? (Also, just a general design thing, why use an `.each()` loop to repeatedly make a call to the _same_ URL to get the same JSON? I'd suggest getting the JSON first, then putting the `.each()` loop inside the success callback.)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c6vnp/7/
I replaced the url with the sample data and erased the .get call. But it should be giving the same results as it would if you were to get the data with ajax.

What I did was

```
var myoptions = jQuery.extend ({ url: "error" }, options);
```

instead of

```
myoptions = jQuery.extend ({ url: "error" }, options);
```

also, the whole plugin should be enclosed in

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

and refer to jQuery as $

Also, the commented out line that appends the menu to "this", "this" is NOT what you want it to be at that point. You should define $this = $(this) at the beginning of your plugin so that you can always have access to the original "this". It is very important to keep tabs on what "this" is. I always console.log(this); every so often, just to make sure.